# With Bazels `http_archive` - is there a way to add outside files to repository after downloading

Tags: bazel, patch, bazel-rules

With Bazel I'm building an external library using http_archive together with some patches which bring additional files.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
    http_archive(
        name="some-lib",
        build_file="@my-project//some-lib:BUILD.some-lib",
        url="https://example/download/some-lib.tar.gz",
        sha256="x"
        patches=[
            "//@abc/bcd.txt",
        ],
    )
```

I am trying to add additional file  through patches "//@abc/bcd.txt" which will be later used in build file but I am not able to find it. how can I access this patch file and where can I find the patch files so that I can use it in the `BUILD` file I provide? Thanks.

considering if I use  patch_cmds = ["echo 'hello world' >  efg.txt"], then I can find this efg file after extracting the package

```
some-lib
├── BUILD
├── BUILD.some-lib
├── efg.txt
├── ...original files/directory
```

how can I find the location of patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`patches` (at least without also manipulating `patch_tool` and `patch_args`) would not add files it finds, but will apply them as patches. I.e. if you wanted to create a `efg.txt` file in the root of your unpacked archive, the `add_efg_txt.patch` could look like this:

```
--- /dev/null
+++ efg.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello world
```

As to where to store the patch files themselves? Theoretically anywhere, but likely in the same (bzl) package where you invoke `http_archive`. You then use their bazel [label](https://bazel.build/concepts/labels) in the list of [`patches`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/http#http_archive-patches) attribute of `http_archive`.

Once the file has been patched into existence, you can refer to it inside the `BUILD` file in the root of the package (in your example): `@my-project//some-lib:BUILD.some-lib` and if exported from there and visible also from your workspace via `@some-lib//:efg.txt`.

---

To respond to your comment. No, you cannot access the source file or its content with `patch_cmds`, check out the [docs](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/http#http_archive-patch_cmds_win) [emphasis added]:

> Sequence of Bash commands to be applied on Linux/Macos ***after patches are applied***.

In other words, this is for action(s) you can perform to wrap up the patching session.

As stated before, by far the most straightforward way to patch file into existence is to provide it as a diff. You can create one by comparing your file to "nothing" (`/dev/null`):

```bash
$ diff -u /dev/null efg.txt > add_efg_txt.patch
```

You could in theory write your own `dump_to_efg_txt.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cat > efg.txt
```

And pass that into [`patch_tool`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/http#http_archive-patch_tool) which is fed the file(s) from [`patches`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/http#http_archive-patches) via `stdin`. But this approach would be problematic in multiple ways and really would not make much sense unless confusion was the ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a pretty simple [custom repository rule](https://bazel.build/extending/repo). Something like this:

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:utils.bzl", "patch", "workspace_and_buildfile")

def _my_rule_impl(ctx):
    ctx.download_and_extract(
        url = ctx.attr.url,
        sha256 = ctx.attr.sha256,
    )
    workspace_and_buildfile(ctx)
    patch(ctx, patches = ctx.attr.patches)
    ctx.file("a_new_file", content = ctx.read(ctx.attr.new_file), executable = False)

my_rule = repository_rule(
    implementation = _my_rule_impl,
    attrs = {
        "url": attr.string(),
        "sha256": attr.string(),
        "patches": attr.label_list(),
        "new_file": attr.label(),
        "build_file": attr.label(allow_single_file = True),
        "build_file_content": attr.string(),
        "patch_args": attr.string_list(default = ["-p0"]),
        "workspace_file": attr.label(),
        "workspace_file_content": attr.string(),
    },
)
```

The `ctx.file` line is what's actually creating your new file. The rest of it is basically the core functionality of `http_archive`, to get the base set up.

This `ctx` is different from the one in normal rules, the documentation is under [repository_ctx](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/builtins/repository_ctx).  There are some other helpers in [util.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/build_defs/repo/utils.bzl) for doing the basic things, so you can build on top with your custom functionality.